# DataTemplate with data binding from two sources

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin-binding

I have a data template with an image which has Source property binding to the default source(the observable collection, it works fine). The issue is that I need its IsVisible property binding to other source(an object declared in my code behind) but when running app I'm getting this on console:

`Binding: 'ScrollEvent' property not found on 'Xamarin.Forms.Binding', target property: 'FFImageLoading.Forms.CachedImage.IsVisible'`

Relevant parts of my code:

MyPage.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MapMsgSend">

 ...

   <ffimageloading:CachedImage
        Source="{Binding imageSource}" 
        IsVisible="{Binding Source={Binding MyPage}, Path=ScrollEvent.Visibility}">
   </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

 ...

</DataTemplate>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs (related part)

```
namespace Project.XAML
{
    public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
       public MyPage(){
         this.BindingContext=this;
       }
       public IsScrolling ScrollEvent = new IsScrolling() { ShowImage = true };
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public class IsScrolling : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      private bool _ShowImage { get; set; }
      public bool ShowImage
      {
          get { return _ShowImage; }
          set
          {
              _ShowImage = value;
              NotifyPropertyChange("ShowImage");
          }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      void NotifyPropertyChange(string PropName)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
      }
}

//default value
public IsScrolling ScrollEvent = new IsScrolling() { ShowImage = true };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax should be something like this

```
<ContentPage ... x:Name="page">
...

<ffimageloading:CachedImage
    Source="{Binding imageSource}" 
    IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference page},Path=ScrollEvent.Visibility}"
```

you can only bind to **public properties**

this is public, but it is not a property

```
public IsScrolling ScrollEvent = new IsScrolling() { ShowImage = true };
```

it needs `get` and/or `set` to be a property, like this

```
public IsScrolling ScrollEvent { get; set; } = new IsScrolling() { ShowImage = true };
```

Comment: I don't have any doubt that you know how to do this, you helped me a lot of times already. But I was doing exactly as you said. I just moved it back now. It crashs with exception:
```Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 282:57. Can not find the object referenced by `Page`
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ReferenceExtension.ProvideValue (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x000bf] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\MarkupExtensions\ReferenceExtension.cs:42
  at MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML.Page+<InitializeComponent>_anonXamlCDataTemplate_8.LoadDataTemplate () [0x00a2c] in ```

Comment: I will accept your answer since it might be the right way to do it, but if you could help me a little bit more in finding why it's crashing I would be very happy.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear - "Position 282:57. Can not find the object referenced by `Page`".  Are you using consistent naming and casing with your names?  You might want to use a different name, as "Page" might conflict with some built in types.

Comment: actually, the name is ChatPage, I renamed to post the question and keep it to don't cause confusion. And of course, it exists... it's the same page where I want to do the bind.

Comment: does the name you use in `x:Name` match the name you use in `x:Reference`?

Comment: I didn't give any x:Name to this Page. Do I have to do it? Even if the object to binding to is declared only in code behind?

Comment: I have just did it but same problem: Binding: 'ScrollEvent' property not found on 'MasterDetailPageNavigation.XAML.ChatPage'. And yes, I'm giving same name to x:Reference. I think a workaround will be setting a Label or other view that binds its visibility to ScrollEvent and than do 
```<ffimageloading:CachedImage IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThatLabel, Path=IsVisible}}">```. This should work since I can set Label binding context directly in code behind.

Comment: ScrollEvent needs to be a public property

Comment: It is... public IsScrolling ScrollEvent

Comment: No it is not.  Please lookup C# properties

Comment: Well, this is what I have:  ```public IsScrolling ScrollEvent = new IsScrolling() { ShowImage = true }; ```

Comment: Properties require a get and/or set

Comment: I've just edited question with implementation. Is it wrong?